# Convergence of the sum of $10^n/((n+1)4^{2n+1})$ to inf when $n=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I tried to do the ratio test, but I keep getting $5/2$ as the answer which means that it diverges. However, the answer in the book says that the series is absolutely converging.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Note that $4^{2n+1} = 4^1 \cdot 4^{2n} = 4 \cdot (4^2)^n = 4 \cdot 16^n$.

So, when you apply the ratio test, you should get $\dfrac{10}{16} = \dfrac{5}{8} < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

We have for $a = \dfrac{10}{16} = \dfrac{5}{8}$,

$S=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{10^n}{(n+1)4^{2n+1}} = \dfrac{1}{4a}\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n+1}a^{n+1} = \dfrac{f(a)}{4a}$.

$f'(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = x\left(1+x+x^2+...\right) = \dfrac{x}{1-x} = -1+\dfrac{1}{1-x} \to f(x) = - x -\ln(1-x) + C \to f(0) = C \to C = 0 \to f(x) = -x-\ln(1-x) \to f(a) = -a-\ln(1-a)$. Thus:

$S = \dfrac{-a-\ln(1-a)}{4a}$